# Boot repair problems?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7

I have a windows 8 laptop (Compaq CQ45) I uninstalled 8. I installed Ubuntu 13.10 on my laptop. But know I installed windows 7. I cant get it on start-up to ask me what I would like to do. How can this problem be fixed.

Comment: Sounds like an overwritten MBR. Wouldn't have happend with UEFI booting and Windows 8. Go ahead and use Windows 7 on Windows 8 machines, shoot yourself in the foot.

Comment: @LiveWireBT what's wrong using windows 7 in UEFI machines?

Comment: @Akronix Probably not much more than using XP on the same machine, if you create a legacy partition table before installing any new operating system in legacy mode (or you know how to avoid that and mixing GPT and MBR) and you can cope with bootloaders overwriting each other. (Or hardware issues like missing 512e support on non-SP1 media, newer ACPI code and so forth.) Also tools like `BCDboot` (`-f UEFI` option) play way more nicer on Windows 8 together with other operating systems. UEFI is the long awaited solution to a lot of the BIOS/MBR mess. Blindly installing W7 is the worst you can do.

Comment: @LiveWireBT Thank you very much for the information, seriously. But I have to say, couldn't you have explained to user259035 something like that when you were asking his/her question?

Comment: @Akronix I think you are right, this would have been reasonable. But I don't see users blindly installing Windows 7, just because some very vocal people hate(d) Windows 8(.0 for just being new), acting reasonable. At last, providing detailed explanations to people that don't want to listen is a waste of my time. So my initial comment was some sort of compromise. :\

Answer (score 1):

1. Set up a live ubuntu boot-repair usb/CD.
2. Boot the system from there
3. launch boot repair from the dash
4. Select Recomended repair. Copy the output of the paste.ubuntu generated here, just in
   case.
5. Reboot

More info and explanations for setting up and using boot-repair here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 0):

Try boot-repair, by booting into Ubuntu from Live-USB or Live-DVD.

Install 'boot repair' with Terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) by typing the following commands:

1.sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair

2.sudo apt-get update

3.sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair

Run 'boot-repair':

1.sudo boot-repair

Click on Recommended repair and write on a piece of paper the new URL that will appear. 
Finally, reboot your PC!